# API Keys for REST

Tags: hash, php, rest, hmac

So I'm developing a RESTful API, but I can't for the life of me understand how API keys work. I'm using PHP, which has an HMAC function, which I've read is a good way to sign requests, but what I don't understand is as follows.

I'm not suppose to send the API key to the client, but the client with HMAC is suppose to take the message, which is usually an array of elements involved in the request and the API key. How is the user/client expected to make a signature including the API key if the user isn't supposed to have the API key?

Comment: duplicate of: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18684/how-to-implement-an-api-key-mechanism ?

Comment: @schroeder Okay, I understand this concept, but how do you securely store the api key to the user's client? How does the user's client possibly know they're key prior to making a call to the api? You can't send it back as a return value with the login, can you? At that point, the api key is sent through communication and would be compromised, right?

Comment: @schroeder Also, what if my user wants to make a call to the api from any computer? Does it boil down to I don't understand the concept OR need a different approach to the problem of authentication?

Comment: @JeffreyGreen generally the client has to come to your web app, authenticate themselves, request for the key and then store it somewhere "safe" in their application.

Comment: @JeffreyGreen why is data returned from the server compromised? If you use HTTPS, which should be the minimum requirement for any RESTful API, then any information exchanged between the server and the client is secure. So why do you think it is compromised?

Comment: @ParthShah is there anything one should do to secure this? Or is it just get their user/pass and give them the key, to which that's the source for the rest of the API calls they want to make?

Comment: @ParthShah I still don't understand https and what exactly it does. Building this all from scratch with not much background on REST or https.

Comment: @JeffreyGreen I am not a PHP developer, so I can't give you any advise on how to develop a REST API in PHP. However, please learn about HTTPS and how to set it up for your PHP website first. It is extremely important you do this and there are plenty of articles you can find on this. Once you understand what HTTPS is for, what it does for you, and how to set it up for your website, then learn about user authentication. Building the API from that point on will be really simple.

Comment: `I'm not suppose to send the API key to the client` who told you this and in what context? The context of what this sentence means is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unless I'm mistaken, I was misunderstanding the inherent concept of API keys, in that, I should be able to give the API key to a user who has authenticated their username and password and work with the key from there. I assume this isn't even the safest or best way, but after implementing HTTPS as mentioned by Parth Shah, I think most of my problems will be avoided and I can begin implementing the start of a basic authentication procedure for my API calls in which I will not be receiving the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how this is handled by companies who use APIs extensively. A good example is [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) or [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php).

You will see that there is at some point some information you have to

- either get from some place (in the case of Google - [the API Console](https://console.developers.google.com)) and use as part of the authentication (this is typically the key you are mentioning); this is usually used for application-to-application communication
- or use a user-based authentication protocol like [oAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

In your case the way to go is oAuth, where users do not store anything themselves (there is a cookie stored for them but they are not aware of that). You can then use third-party systems (Google, Twitter, LinkedIn, ...) to handle the authentication on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

The API Key is usually used to identify the environment/privilages for a particular user in a multi tenant environment.

say, you have an application where you have three customers A,B and C. all the three customers have completely different settings/ use different features etc.

Now say, if you want to create a new user under customer C, the unique API key for customer C will be used to identify the settings/resources/environment/privilages for the users under C.